# Fine tunning a Rapsberri Pi 2 B+ full 0.12 node

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization, nodes, raspberry-pi

I'm running a 0.12 Raspnode (raspberri Pi 2 B+ full node)

I've made the full node syncing in a laptop to speed up the process. Then, after moving all the files successfully and starting the full node in the rPi I have noted that it cannot completely sync and it is most of the time a few blocks away from 100% height.

The rPi is running only bitcoind and I've modified with `renice` the priority to its assigned PID.

I would like to know what are the parameters and values I need to change in order to get a fully synchronized node (100% height).

The following options comes to mind:

- Increase the relayfee parameter? (current value
  minrelaytxfee=0.00005)
- Decrease the memory assigned to the UXTO? (current value
  maxmempool=150)
- Increase or decrease the prune value? (current is
  prune=30000)
- Decrease the free-tx limit? (current at limitfreerelay=10)

If you need any additional info feel free to ask for it, I would gladly provide it.

Edit: seems that blocks are being produced faster than the processing power of the Rpi 2 B+ can handle.. so it never gets sync'ed.. its always behind the last block.

Comment: Which version of the Pi do you have?

Comment: Raspberry Pi B+

Comment: Yeah, I've read before that the first generation Pis don't have enough computing power to keep up. I'm running a node on a Pi 2B, and even that took almost four weeks to catch up to the network (I tried. For science.). ;)

Comment: Im sorry , its a 2B+

Answer (score 1):

You do need to store data on an external SSD disk (USB).

If your data and swap are on SSD media, you can use all those options (they won't matter much).

I don't recommend to use Pi 2 (any version), it's a waste of time. It can barely keep up, it becomes useless for anything else and each time you restart the OS or bitcoind you need to wait several hours for it to catch up.